# Deleting unneeded service accounts from gcloud permission denied to owner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, terraform-provider-gcp

I have a number of unused service accounts in gcloud that I want to remove.

```
                          Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
*       mike@mycompany.com
        tf@mycompany-terraform-admin.iam.gserviceaccount.com
        tf@mycompany-terraform-admin-20190506.iam.gserviceaccount.com
        tf@mycompany-terraform-admin-20190727.iam.gserviceaccount.com
        tf@mycompany-terraform-admin-20190725.iam.gserviceaccount.com
        tf-service@mycompany-terraform-admin-20200422.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

However, running

```
gcloud iam service-accounts delete tf@mycompany-terraform-admin-20190506.iam.gserviceaccount.com

ERROR: (gcloud.iam.service-accounts.delete) PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission  iam.serviceAccounts.delete is required to perform this operation on service account projects/-/serviceAccounts/tf@mycompany-terraform-admin-20190506.iam.gserviceaccount.com.
```

I am the owner of the account. What more permissions do I need?

Aside: I seem to spend >90% of my time with gcp on permissions instead of actually doing stuff and have not been able to find a clear write-up of this. Anyone knows a good explanation on how to use service-accounts effectively.

Comment: Use the command `gcloud auth list` and double check that you are using an account that has the `Owner` role or another supported role such as `roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin` or `roles/editor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to [delete a service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#iam-service-accounts-delete-gcloud), your permissions must be higher than the editor role (`roles/editor`) or you must be granted the *Service Account Admin* role (`roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin`).

I suggest that you verify the current account that you are using to make sure that the IAM policies set on it respect the minimum that is required for the actions to be completed successfully.

In regards to the use of Service Accounts, I suggest you consider the following docs:

- [Understanding Service Accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts); This will give you a detailed, but high level overview of that Service Accounts are, how they work, deletion and recreation of service accounts and best practices.
- [Service Account Overview](https://medium.com/google-cloud/service-accounts-on-google-cloud-platform-add6ab4ec4fe); This is a very general, but well written overview of Service Accounts. It contains an easy to follow and descriptive explination regarding each step that may need to be taken when using service accounts.
- [A Hitchhiker’s Guide to GCP Service Account Impersonation in Terraform](https://medium.com/google-cloud/a-hitchhikers-guide-to-gcp-service-account-impersonation-in-terraform-af98853ebd37); Adding this here as I noticed that your service accounts were linked to the use of Terraform and many people use Terraform within their projects.
- [Managing Service Accounts](https://medium.com/@prashantapaudel/gcp-certification-series-5-2-managing-service-accounts-2e7ea05ef7b9); This is a very detailed (and thus, long) post explaining how to better manage Service Accounts.
- [IAM FAQs](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/faq); These FAQs, even though very general, they do cover a good chunk of the issues that are to be had with IAM. As Service Accounts are a subset of IAM, I suggest that this be consulted as needed.

I hope that this is helpful. IAM is very big and can take a bit of time to get just right. Keep in mind that once IAM is set up right, you may not need to look at it again.

Comment: As a note to your answer: The Editor role can delete a service account. To verify `gcloud iam roles describe roles/editor` and check for the permissions `iam.serviceAccounts.delete` and `iam.serviceAccountKeys.delete`

Comment: Thanks. This has been very helpful. Due to me using the word delete, I did not get the correct question across, but I found using the links that gcloud auth revoke ... allows me to get rid of superfluous terraform service accounts.